Browser Extension doesn't change innerHTML
The script seems to run correctly but it doesn't edit anything. If I put the script in the console it works, but by clicking the extension it returns an error that the innerHTML for the given element is undefined.
I'm pretty sure I have all the right permissions. I'm also quite sure it's not because the DOM has to load.
manifest.json
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Example name",
    "description": "",
    "version": "1.0",
    "icons": {
      "16": "icon16.png",
      "32": "icon32.png",
      "48": "icon48.png",
      "128": "icon128.png"
    },
    "action": {

    },
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "scripting"],
    "background": {
      "service_worker": "background.js"
    }
  }

background.js
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: {tabId: tab.id},
    files: ['content.js']
  });
});

And content.js is just one line changing document.getElementById("randomID").innerHTML to something else, which like I said works in the console, not while executed by the extension.
I've only tried searching for some solutions online but couldn't find anything helpful.

If you put a console.log() call in content.js, do you see the log message?

It usually means the element is inside the iframe. When you use devtools console you probably inspected the iframe first, which selected it as console's context. Assuming the iframe is same-origin you can add allframes:true to executeScript and add a check for element's existence before modifying it.
